# Zero length and zero permission files created on NFS mount

Tags: linux, centos6, nfs4

We have one NFS share mounted from one server to another (first is exporting, second is mounting).

Sometimes when the file is created on the server, which has the NFS volume mounted, the file ends up with zero length and zero permission so it is not possible to access it any other way than on exporting server as root.

It happens once a 100 or 150 files. There is nothing in the logs on any of the servers.

NFS is v4. Both servers are on local LAN. There is no visible network issues.

OS: CentOS release 6.4 (Final) (both servers)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by downgrading to NFSv3.

From then, no problems appeared.